# How to route with id in URL

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-routing

I want to route with the URL `accept_form/1` which I get after clicking an anchor tag.

What should I write in my Route?

I am trying this:

```php
Route::get('accept_form/{$id}', 'Controller@accept_form');
```

View :

```php
<a href="{{ url('accept_form/' . $key->id) }}" class="small-box-footer">
   More info <i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-right"></i>
</a>
```

Comment: Share your code instead of image.

Comment: stack overflow grammar standard didn't let me do that.

Comment: `accept_form/{$id}` should be `accept_form/{id}`

Answer (score 2):

Give a specific name of your routes like below.

```
Route::get('/accept_form/{id}', 'YourController@yourMethod')->name('accept_form');
```

Then pass parameters with array along with route function,

```
<a href="{{ route('accept_form', [$id])}}"> More info</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

Named your route,

```
Route::get('/accept_form/{id}', 'YourController@yourMethod')->name('accept_form');
```

Then You can use,

```
<a href="{{ route('accept_form', $id)}}"> More info</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

you can do like this

```
{{ route('accept_form', ['id'=>$id])}}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change Route to

```
Route::get('accept_form/{id}', 'Controller@accept_form');
```

Anchor tag

```
<a href="{{ url('accept_form', $id)}}" class="small-box-footer"> More Indo </a>
```